# How to select column value depends on its existence?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to write query that should return one column depends on existence of value in 2 columns in this way:

The columns are: C1 and C2 and they are in the same table T. If C1 exists then return C1, if C1 doesn't exist return C2.

Comment: I know I should use if or case, but I'm nor sure how.

Comment: refer my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select case when isnull(C1,'')<>'' then C1
            else C2
       end as Column_name
from table T
```

[Case statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181765.aspx) is used here.

Comment: This would return C1 if C1 is not null. If C1 is null, then C2 will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when isnull(C1,'')<>'' then C1
            when isnull(C2,'')<>'' then C2
       end as Column_name
from table T
```

Comment: The question does not have a condition on C2's existence. It says "*if C1 doesn't exist return C2*".